# in rails set config.action_mailer.default_url_options to whatever the current host of the app is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, host

How can I dynamically set the host in a config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => THE_HOST}
```

This is so the app works correctly when in staging and when in production. Our staging server  is stage.app.com, and links need to go there.

Answer (score 5):

In `config/environments/production.rb` do this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'app.com' }
```

and in `config/environments/staging.rb` do this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'stage.app.com' }
```

As @BrettBender commented:

> You do not need to dynamically set the host. For an app in production, production.rb will be evaluated. For an app running in staging environment, rails will load the staging file automatically (same with development or any custom environments you define)

Comment: First, a typo: you've put `config/production.rb` when you mean `config/environments/production.rb`, and the same with staging.  To expand a bit on this answer, you do not need to dynamically set the host.  For an app in production, production.rb will be evaluated.  For an app running in staging environment, rails will load the staging file automatically (same with development or any custom environments you define).

Comment: Thanks @BrettBender. I incorporated what you said into my answer.

Comment: What if I have two sites running in production mode? One is real production, other - for QA.

Comment: @Paul then do this: `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['MAIL_HOST'] }` and set the MAIL_HOST environment variable on each server

Comment: How do I run the app in staging environment?

Comment: rails server RAILS_ENV=staging

Comment: The beauty of @nicholaides way is that important configuration settings are extracted to externally-configured environment variables, which is the way to do it (see foreman environments and heroku config vars).  (Set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` in `config/application.rb` per above)

Answer (score -2):

Add this to a before filter in application_controller:

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = {:host => request.host_with_port}
```

Comment: This is definitely a bad practice. You tied sending emails to requests, thus any email sending from non-request based invocations will fail: rake tasks, resque workers, etc.